# AWS Serverless Template Configurations with Custom Authorization and Rest API

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am a newbie to AWS Lambda Services. I have created a serverless lambda method and successfully deployed it on the AWS cloud.

Next I created a Lambda custom Authorizer and configured the API Gateway for the Lambda method and custom Authorizer.

As, I need to expose many other server less lambda methods therefore I decided to move my lambda method in a serverless .Net API Project. I can deploy this api project to AWS cloud and then manually I can setup the authorizer to use my custom Authorize lambda method.

**The struggling part is**, I want to configure all these things through serverless.template file.

I am struggling in getting the **RESTAPIID** for my custom authorizer method and how to set authorizer for my lambda function using the serverless.template file. Below is the configurations I have done.
Also, how to get **AuthorizerUri**?

I do not want to hard code any thing.

```
    "Resources" : {
**//How I can create this serverless function to use my custom authorizer?**
    "Create" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Serverless::Function",      
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "Osn.Ott.Telco.Connector.UI.Web.Controllers.V10::Osn.Ott.Telco.Connector.UI.Web.Controllers.V10.SubscriptionController::Create",
        "Runtime": "dotnetcore2.1",
        "CodeUri": "",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Role": null,
        "FunctionName" : "CreateCustomer",
        "Policies": [ "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole" ],
        "Events": {
          "PutResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/create",
              "Method": "POST"
            }            
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "CustomAuthorizer" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer",
        "Properties" : {
            "AuthorizerUri" : {"Fn::GetAtt" : [ "Create", "Arn"]},
            "IdentitySource" : "method.request.header.Authorization,method.request.context.resourcePath, method.request.context.path",
            "Name"           : "CustomAuthorizer",
            "Type"           : "REQUEST",
**//How I can get this id?**
            "RestApiId" : {"Fn::GetAtt" : [ "ServerlessRespApi", ""]}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

AWS announced support for [AWS Serverless Application Model Supports Amazon API Gateway Authorizers](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-sam-supports-amazon-api-gateway-authorizers/) last week (it could be done previously as well but then one had to use inline Swagger in the SAM template).

There are a few GitHub examples linked from the page the above, and I guess that the [Lambda Request Authorizer](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/tree/master/examples/2016-10-31/api_lambda_request_auth) is closest to your problem. The code below is copied from the [template.yaml](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/examples/2016-10-31/api_lambda_request_auth/template.yaml). Please also see the [API Auth Object](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api-auth-object) part of the AWS SAM specification.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: API Gateway with Lambda Token Authorizer
Resources:
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: MyLambdaRequestAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          MyLambdaRequestAuthorizer:
            FunctionPayloadType: REQUEST
            FunctionArn: !GetAtt MyAuthFunction.Arn
            # FunctionInvokeRole: !Ref MyRole
            Identity:
              QueryStrings:
                - auth
              # NOTE: Additional options:
              # Headers:
              #   - Authorization
              # StageVariables:
              #   - AUTHORIZATION
              # Context:
              #   - authorization
              # ReauthorizeEvery: 100 # seconds

  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./src
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Events:
        GetRoot:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
            Path: /
            Method: get
            Auth:
              Authorizer: NONE
        GetUsers:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
            Path: /users
            Method: get

  MyAuthFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./src
      Handler: authorizer.handler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10

Outputs:
  ApiURL:
    Description: "API URL"
    Value: !Sub 'https://${MyApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/'
```

Comment: in my case auth is not a valid key in  MyApi: section.

Comment: @muhammadkashif support for API Gateway authorizers in AWS SAM were [announced](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-sam-supports-amazon-api-gateway-authorizers/) just 10 days ago but should be  _available in all regions where AWS Lambda is available_ (according to the announcement). You have not specified in what way the `Auth` is not valid. My guess is that you use a tool that validates the CloudFormation template before it is being deployed that has not yet added support for the `Auth` object.